# Solve : $\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)=\sqrt{2}\sin\sqrt{x}$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve : $\sin\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)+\cos\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)=\sqrt{2}\sin\sqrt{x}$

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\sin\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)=\sin\sqrt{x}$$

$$\sin\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)=\sin\sqrt{x}$$
$$\sin\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)-\sin\sqrt{x}=0$$
$$2\sin\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{2}-\dfrac{\pi}{4}}{2}\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{3\sqrt{x}}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{4}}{2}\right)=0$$

$$\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{2}-\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)=2n\pi \text { or } 
 \left(\dfrac{3\sqrt{x}}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)=(2n+1)\pi$$

$$\sqrt{x}=4n\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{2} \text { or } \sqrt{x}=\dfrac{4n\pi}{3}+\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

$$x=\left(4n\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)^2 \text { or } x=\left(\dfrac{4n\pi}{3}+\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)^2 \text { where n $\in$ I}$$

But actual answer is $$x=\left(4n\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)^2 \text { or } x=\left(\dfrac{4m\pi}{3}+\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)^2 \text { where n,m $\in$ W}$$

I tried to find the mistake but didn't get any breakthroughs.

Comment: What are $I$ and $W$? I don't really see a difference between your answer and the actual answer.

Comment: I is the integer set and W is the whole number set

Comment: You are using the same notation $n$ for possibly different integers $n$ and $m$.

Comment: What are $I$ and $W$. These are not standard notations.

Comment: we generally write like this only, if you have $\cos x\cos2x=0$, it is written as $x=\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}{2} \text { or } x=\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}{4}$, so using the same variable doesn't cause any harm.

Comment: @KaboMurphy, here they are used in the sense of integer set and whole number set respectively.

Answer (score 2):

First, 
$\sin \alpha = \sin \beta \iff 
 \beta \equiv \alpha \pmod{2 \pi}
 \quad \text{or} \quad 
 \beta \equiv \pi - \alpha \pmod{2 \pi}$

So, from

$$ \sin\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right) = \sin\sqrt{x} $$

You could have argued

$$ \sqrt x = 2m\pi + \dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{4}
  \qquad \text{or} \qquad
  \pi - \sqrt x = -2n\pi + \dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{4}$$

$$ \dfrac{\sqrt x}{2} = 2m\pi +\dfrac{\pi}{4} 
   \qquad \text{or} \qquad
   \sqrt x = \dfrac{8n+3}{6}\pi$$

$$ x = \left( 4m\pi + \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right)^2
   \qquad \text{or} \qquad
   x = \left( \dfrac{8n+3}{6}\pi \right)^2$$

Note that, when $x = \left( 4m\pi + \dfrac 12\pi \right)^2$, then
$\sqrt x = \left| m\pi + \dfrac 12\pi \right|$ but we need to have $\sqrt x = m\pi +\dfrac 12\pi$. So we need to require $m \in \mathbb W$. Similarly, we will need to require $n \in \mathbb W$.

Comment: simple question: in 6th line of my solution, $\sqrt{x}=\dfrac{4n\pi}{3}+\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, if $n=-1$, then $\sqrt{x}=\dfrac{-5\pi}{6}$, and you can put this value of $\sqrt{x}$ in the original equation, it is getting satisfied, can you explain this?

Comment: Simple answer. I'm getting old? I'll try to fix it.

Comment: You made some errors in the steps you skipped.  For instance, if $$\sqrt{x} = 2m\pi + \frac{\sqrt{x}}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4}$$ then $$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2} = 2m\pi + \frac{\pi}{4}$$ Multiplying both sides by $2$ gives $$\sqrt{x} = \color{red}{4}m\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$$  You also made an error in solving the equation $\pi - \sqrt{x} = -2n\pi + \frac{\sqrt{x}}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4}$ for $\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig - Thanks. I tried to fix it. I'm getting to the point where I won't be able to contribute to MSE any more. But I'm holding on for as long as I can.

Comment: You did fix the errors, and I am glad that you continue to contribute to the site.

Answer (score 0):

First we square both sides to get
$$
\begin{align*}
\left(\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)\right)^2&=\left(\sqrt{2}\sin\left(\sqrt{x}\right)\right)^2,\\
\sin^2\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)+\cos^2\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)+2\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)&=2\sin^2\left(\sqrt{x}\right),\\
1+2\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)=2\sin^2\left(\sqrt{x}\right),\\
-2\sin^2\left(\sqrt{x}\right)+\sin\left(\sqrt{x}\right)+1=0.
\end{align*}$$

Let $y:=\sin(\sqrt{x})$ meaning we have the polynomial $-2y^2+y+1=0$. Factoring gives us $(2y+1)(y-1)=0$ meaning that $\sin(\sqrt{x})=1$ and $\sin(\sqrt{x})=-1/2$.

If $\sin(\sqrt{x})=1$ then $\sqrt{x}=\pi/2 + 2\pi n$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ which means that $x=\pi^2(4n+1)^2/4$.

If $\sin(\sqrt{x})=-1/2$ then the principle angle (i.e. angle in quadrant one), $\alpha$, is $\alpha=\pi/6+2\pi n$. Since $\sin$ is negative in quadrants three and four, $\sqrt{x}=7\pi/6 +2\pi n$ and $\sqrt{x}=11\pi/6 + 2\pi n$. This means that the solutions are $x=\pi^2(12n+7)^2/36$ and $\pi^2(12n+11)^2/36$.

Therefore, the solutions are 
$$
\begin{align}
x&=\frac{\pi^2(4n+1)^2}{4},\\
x&=\frac{\pi^2\left(12n+7\right)^2}{36},\\
x&=\frac{\pi^2\left(12n+11\right)^2}{36}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: downvoting it because we should avoid squaring as it introduces false solutios . Problem can be easily solved without squaring.